# What are these designations on a sensor datasheet?

Tags: image-sensor, units

I'm working with image sensor Anafocus Lince5M.

In its datasheet there are some designations that I can't understand (underlined).

[image]

What are these designations?

And how to calculate threshold sensitivity of this image sensor?

Comment: If that's part of your question then put it in the question where the readers will see it. Use the 'edit' link.

Comment: RMS=root mean square, FS=full scale

Answer (score 1):

Image sensors are sensitive to photons, and at the most basic level, each "pixel" effectively counts the number of photons that they sense. That's the **DN** or digital number, which are more important when you're working with raw data. (Before processing, filtering, etc.)

**RMS** is [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), common terminology for averaging a continuously changing value.

**PRNU** is photo-response non-uniformity. It's a way of characterizing the performance of individual sensors across the CMOS image sensor.

**FS** just means full-scale.

**LE** is linearity error. From the [EMVA Standard for Characterization of Image Sensors and Cameras](https://www.emva.org/wp-content/uploads/EMVA1288-3.0.pdf):

> The linearity error is then defined as the mean of the difference of the maximal deviation to the minimal deviation
>   $$
> LE = \frac{max(\delta_y)-min(\delta_y)}{2}
> $$
>   and thus defines the mean of the positive and negative deviation from the linear regression.

I'm not sure what you mean by threshold sensitivity. Do you mean the minimum threshold at which it detects light? That seems to be given in the `6V/lux-s` (volts per lux-second) sensitivity property. However, you'll have to work from there; I'm not an expert in image sensors (sorry!).

Answer (score 1):

The gain of those cmos sensors is typically expressed in electrons (e-) per data number (**DN**) of the integrated ADC. DN12 simply referes to one data number in a 12-bit space of numbers. In respect to the FPN of FR) of 1024 DNs (1/1024 < 0.1%).

[**RMS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) (**r**oot **m**ean **s**quare) is a common way of expressing the mean of a stocchastically distributed value (like noise).

The [**PRNU**](https://harvestimaging.com/blog/?p=916) (**p**hoto **r**esponse **n**on **u**niformity) describes the deviation of the gain of individual pixels from each other (to compensate this deviation, one must "calibrate" each single pixel with a factor and/or an offset).

**LE** (**l**linearity **e**rror) describes the sensor's (non)linearity. Usually, it's the maximum deviation from a linear fit relative to the end of measuring range.
[image]

It's not clear to me what you exactly mean by

> threshold sensitivity

The sensor converts incoming photons into electrons (with a specific gain or quantum efficiency) which are then accumulated in a capacitance. You never want this capacitance to be fully charged, which limits the maximum amount of photons you can detect. On the other hand, the minimum amount of photons you can detect in practice will be limit by dark noise: even if there are no photons, there will still be a small photo current which has to be dominated by your signal (you can't detect a single electron in a stream auf several electrons).
As electrons have to be accumulated, you always can influence the "sensitivity" by choosing an appropriate exposure time or (evetually) the readout rate. Therefore, there is no generally valid threshold.

Comment: Thank you!
The problem is: I know the illumination that'll be created on the surface of sensor (for example 4 lux), and I want to know if it greater than sensor can sense. And, ideally, it'll be good to find output signal (in volts or amperas or etc) for given illumination.

Comment: This depends on your exposure time, as lux describes a photon flux (quantity of photons per time). What you have given is the capacity (mount of electrons you can hold at a given voltage) and the voltage that is accumulated after 1 second (6 V/lux/s). This should help you estimate... just for my understanding: how are you going to interact with this sensor and do you have influence on the sampling rate/exposure time?

Comment: Exposure time is known from datasheet (minimal) it is 4*10^-4 sec. It can be configured, but for calculation we'll take this minimal value.
Nothing can say about interaction yet -- no data (. Just selection of components for camera.

Comment: do you have a real datasheet? all I can find is the product flyer

Comment: the product flyer seems to lack the information you want. to calculate the saturation flux with the given data one needs to know ether the quantum efficiency of the photo diodes or the actual capacity. photo diodes typically have a saturation voltage at about 3V. Using this as a round-about value the sensor would saturate at about 1250 lx.

Comment: I have DS
[link](http://www.cybermanual.com/lince5m-digital-image-sensor-datasheet-e2v.html)